# XML child element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having problems posting the child elements to the xml. Here is my code. If I have many static components in future to add in, how can I post them in xml?

```
<TerminalStatusRequest>
    <TerminalID>AT0001</TerminalID>
    <ReaderID>SC0001</ReaderID>
    <ComponentName>Printer</ComponentName>
    <ComponentValue>Active</ComponentValue>
</TerminalStatusRequest>
```

Comment: What do you (want to) use for these operations: standard `XmlElement` or Linq-to-XML (`XElement`)? Will the future content be structured directly under the root or can it be hierarchically structured on several levels?

Comment: In the future there will be more component that will be added. So how do I achieve that.Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this way. You can also add many node in writer oject

```
 string path=@"c:\\test.xml";
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("TerminalStatusRequest");
                writer.WriteElementString("TerminalID","AT0001");
                writer.WriteElementString("ReaderID", "SC0001");
                writer.WriteElementString("ComponentName","Printer");
                writer.WriteElementString("ComponentValue","Active");

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }
```